# Create a column in dataframe that contains information on the other columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I would like to generate a column in a big data frame which is contains the information of the other columns.
I am giving a very small reproducible example:

```
tax <- data.frame(
Family = c("Brassicacae", "Pinaceae", "Rosaceae", "Liliaceae"), 
Genus = c("NA" ,"Pinus", "NA", "Lilia"),
Species = c("NA" ,"Pinus_sylvestris", "NA", "Calochortus nuttallii"))
```

I would like to create a column called tax_rank where your taxonomy reaches species will have the value `species` but if you reach higher rank like genus than the value will be `genus` or `family`like this output:

```
tax <- data.frame(
Family = c("Brassicacae", "Pinaceae", "Rosaceae", "Liliaceae"), 
Genus = c("NA" ,"Pinus", "NA", "Lilia"),
Species = c("NA" ,"Pinus_sylvestris", "NA", "Calochortus nuttallii"),
tax_rank = c("family" ,"species", "family", "species"))
```

But I would like to do it automatically with a big dataset, is it possible with `dplyr`?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In `base R`, you can use `max.col` on the non-NA values and choose `ties.method = "last"` to keep the latest non-NA value.

```r
names(tax)[max.col(!is.na(tax), ties.method = "last")]
```

This is possible to translate that into `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)
tax %>% 
  mutate(tax_rank = names(tax)[max.col(!is.na(tax), ties.method = "last")])

#        Family Genus               Species tax_rank
# 1 Brassicacae  <NA>                  <NA>   Family
# 2    Pinaceae Pinus      Pinus_sylvestris  Species
# 3    Rosaceae  <NA>                  <NA>   Family
# 4   Liliaceae Lilia Calochortus nuttallii  Species
```

Data (note that I convert `"NA"` to `NA`)

```r
tax <- data.frame(
  Family = c("Brassicacae", "Pinaceae", "Rosaceae", "Liliaceae"), 
  Genus = c(NA ,"Pinus", NA, "Lilia"),
  Species = c(NA ,"Pinus_sylvestris", NA, "Calochortus nuttallii"))
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your dataframe should be with `NA`objects, no as characters:

```
tax <- data.frame(
Family = c("Brassicacae", "Pinaceae", "Rosaceae", "Liliaceae"), 
Genus = c(NA ,"Pinus",NA, "Lilia"),
Species = c(NA,"Pinus_sylvestris", NA, "Calochortus nuttallii"))
```

Then the column you want is the next one

```
tax %>% mutate(tax_rank = ifelse(!is.na(Species), "species", ifelse(!is.na(Genus), "genus", "family")))
```

This is the output

```
       Family Genus               Species tax_rank
1 Brassicacae  <NA>                  <NA>   family
2    Pinaceae Pinus      Pinus_sylvestris  species
3    Rosaceae  <NA>                  <NA>   family
4   Liliaceae Lilia Calochortus nuttallii  species
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `base R`

```
tax$tax_rank <- apply(tax, 1, \(x) tail(names(x)[!is.na(x)], 1))
```

-output

```
> tax
       Family Genus               Species tax_rank
1 Brassicacae  <NA>                  <NA>   Family
2    Pinaceae Pinus      Pinus_sylvestris  Species
3    Rosaceae  <NA>                  <NA>   Family
4   Liliaceae Lilia Calochortus nuttallii  Species
```